# Facebook Mobile App Install Ads wrong preview link

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, mobile, ads

i want to use Facebook Mobile App Install Ads. 
I have the apps on Google Play and App store, 
i have the facebook app, 
i added the native Android and iOS apps.

What i did't do is: 
Install the Facebook SDK for iOS and Android and 
Install Power Editor.

Everything looks fine but when i click on the Ad Preview up right on the screen send me to my website, not to App Store or Google Play. 
Is it like this because i do this on the web and not on an Android or iOS device from Facebook app? 
It is because i didn't install the SDK?

Do i have to complete somewhere the link to Google Play or App Store? Here i can see a text field for this link but not on my app dashboard. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/deep_linking/#native_bookmarks

Here is the link to the new Facebook Mobile App Install Ads: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/mobile-ads/

Thanks in advance,
Stefan

Comment: Have you added your iTunes Store ID and Google Play store ID to the Native iOS app and android app sections of your app details on developers.facebook.com/apps. You will also need to install the SDK for the CPI ads to work. You need to call the API once per new install, such store a flag which is set in the app delegate.

Comment: The App Store and Google play ID is there. My problem is that when i click on the Sample Ad it takes me to my website, not to App Store or Google Play download page

Comment: I believe thats the intended behaviour of the sample link, it will direct you to the app relative to the current platform which in this case is the desktop version. Otherwise how else would the sample link know if you wanted the iTunes store or Play store? Once the ad is running it will direct the user to the relevant store.

Comment: Also you only need to install the SDK if you want a CPI ad, you can run a CPC campaign without installing the SDK however you will be charged even if the user doesn't install your app. Therefore personally I would go for the CPI campaign.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have our SDK integrated in your app in order to use our Facebook Mobile App install ads.

It's a requirement so that we can track the installs that came from Facebook and which ones didn't.

Comment: I have the SDK integrated and app active on the iOS store and I created my first ad. I am experiencing the same issue as was raised by the original poster. The ad preview is going to the website in the site URL field of the app settings. I would expect it to "deep link" to the itunes store. Is this what will happen when a user sees the ad on their mobile device? Or will the be linked to what the ad preview is linking to (my website)?